# Create a .jar from a .dll

Tags: android, dll, jar, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I’m currently trying to create a .jar from a .dll, in order to use it on Android applications. I’m quite new with this technology, so I’ll tried to be as clear as possible.
I have 3 distinct parts:

- A first .dll which is an API, in C++ and developed with Visual studio 2013.
- A second .dll that makes the link between my API and Java code (using JNI, so this is my native library), also developed with Visual studio 2013.
- And my Java code that loads my native library and that implements native functions from API. I use eclipse IDE for that stuff, because I read somewhere that was the easiest way to create a .jar.

This part works pretty well. I created a main test and I get all the information from the API in Java. But now, I would like to create a .jar file that I can use on Android and here comes the crows...
I tried many ways, from the simple .jar export, to the One-Jar method, but nothing worked. I always have a link error on my android platform (functions are recognized on the .jar, but their implementations are not).
So here is my question, how to create a kind of ‘static library’ in a .jar that I can use on Android?
I hope I was clear enough, don’t hesitate to ask me more details.
Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:**
I tried with an Android Library project and my problem is always coming from my loadLibrary() function:

```
public class MyWrapper {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("MyWrapper");    
    }

    public static native int getNegative(int p_number);
    public static native int getPositive(int p_number);
}
```

Every things works fine on my library, but when I use it in android application, I always get this error:

```
01-27 11:31:29.565: E/AndroidRuntime(7089): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 11:31:29.565: E/AndroidRuntime(7089): Process: com.example.wrappertest, PID: 7089
01-27 11:31:29.565: E/AndroidRuntime(7089): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load MyWrapper from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.wrappertest-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.wrappertest-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

My library cound’t be created as static library, to keep the link on the .dll?

Comment: Is is a static (.a) or shared (.so) library you building? You'll only be able to load a shared library from java.

Comment: This is actually a dynamic one (.dll). It works on Java but may be not on android? If I create a .so one, how can I link it with my project because eclipse only takes .dll as native libraries.

Comment: Ah :) that'll be your issue then. As I mention in my answer dll files are windows specific and can't be loaded on Android. You'll need to generate a shared library for Android using the NDK for each of the architectures you're supporting. I'd recommend you check out the examples provided with the NDK as they'll be the easiest way to see how the NDK works :)

Comment: I'm on it :) I will let you know if it works, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .dll file is usually windows specific. If you're wanting to load native code on Android you'll have to look into using the Native Development Kit. The specifics of using the NDK is a bit beyond what can be explained here, but the Android Developer website provides a decent starting point at http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

As for the jar itself, you may want to look into building an Android Library Project instead. This is essentially a means of packaging a jar with some assets (including native libraries) which can be used by an Android Application project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I already use NDK and JNI for retrieve .dll functions in Java. But now I would like to create a .jar with that Java code.

Comment: Ah, in that case my edit may be helpful! Is your jar to be used by an Android Application project, or do you intend to run the jar itself on Android (for example via Bash)? I'm not sure how you'd handle the latter, but Android Library Projects will help with the former. :)

Comment: Unfortunatly, I have the same problem, I don't know how to import and use my .dll as native in my Android library project.

Comment: How are you building the library? Any native code run on Android should be built using the `ndk-build` script built provided with the NDK (this isn't strictly true, but it's the best way in most cases). This should build a libLibraryName.so file (not a .dll) to the libs/abi/ directory of your project (make sure the abi your building for is the same as the device your wanting to run on). Once you've got that it should just be case of loading it from java using System.loadLibrary("LibraryName") (without 'lib' and '.so') and using your JNI bindings which I'm assuming you've already got set up. :)

Comment: Indeed, I used visual studio compiler to create my .dll. I'm going to try with the ndk script. Also, I'm afraid that I don't really understand what is the /abi ?

Comment: Android supports several processor architectures (or Application Binary Interfaces): Arm v5, Arm v7, x86, and Mips. As each of these require different machine code you'll need to build a version of the shared library for each that you want to support. Most Android devices are Arm v7 however, so many applications only provide support for that. The NDK provides easy ways to manage building for all architectures.

Comment: Done, it's working, thank you for your help :) I'm gonna post bellow how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Compile your librarie with `ndk-build`
2. Create an Android Library module
3. Create a Java class and JNI wrapper
4. Disable gradle for `ndk-build` and create `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` in the jni folder
5. Import the `.so` library and pre build it on the `Android.mk`
6. Invoke `ndk-build` manually and its done